# date - insert into - from input type="date"

Tags: php, date, insert-into

i have input "date"..
and i want to insert into the date like this: dd/mm/yyy no like this: yyy/md/dd
who can i do it?

its my code:

HTML:

```
<label for="date">birthdate:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="date" name="date" /><br />
```

php:

```
$_POST['date'] = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
if(mysql_query('insert into users(id, username, password, email, avatar, date, signup_date) values ('.$id.', "'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$avatar.'", "'.$date.'", "'.time().'")'))
```

and...
something else ammm
who can i covert the date to age?

Comment: What is controlling what is posted? i.e. how do you know $_POST['date'] is a valid date?

Comment: Yes...  I forgot it.. I have more things like username..  in the form the action of the form is..  post this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line before `if` statement

```
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: My advice is to give meaningful names to variables, so instead of date2 I'd name the variable formattedDate